# Reading network traffic from the browser using Java code

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, webdriver, network-traffic

Folks,

I was looking for Java capability of reading thru the network tab.
I had a task of hitting a URL in the browser, reading and validate some tags which are fired on page load.
I Know to fetch the View Source Data of the page, but not sure on getting network tab data.

example:

Opening a URL in chrome browser and watching Network tab in the developer tool, i see bunch of Get requests(tags,js etc) getting fired & need to capture this data.

I wanted to know which is the best way to achieve this and great if any code snippet is available.

Cheers

Comment: Just write a proxy in java and configure your browser to use it. Or use an existing solution (such as fiddler).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *HttpClient* to work on api testing. There are many tutorials to work on api testing using Java. For starter you can read about *Apache Http client*.